# MVVM bind combobox contents to a list in a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The problem is with a form that displays a number of combo boxes - the contents of each is  a range of integers. There can be more than one combo box and the integer range can be different for each one, and none of this information is known ahead of time.

The DataTemplate for these comboboxes in XAML is this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListComboboxTemplate">
        <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,0" MinWidth="230" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ListBoxContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                  ... >
```

The ListBoxContent property is an ObservableCollection of strings (I don't know why it's observable - the contents, once they are set, do not change).

The bug shows up when there are 2 or more combo boxes with integer ranges and the ranges are different - the loop that loads them simply assigns the list it calculates to the ListBoxContent property; the result being that all combo boxes end up with the same range (which is of course the last one calculated).

I'm guessing in the ViewModel I need, instead of a simple list, something like a dictionary, keyed to a string* with the values being the ObservableCollection of strings.

*The form displayed has a textblock to the left of the combo box that is bound to a string property - this value would be the keys for the dictionary.

I'm at a loss at how to do this without breaking the pattern. I would think some sort of command that would set the combo box's contents, but I don't know how to get the key needed to the command. I could also be way off base on that idea.

Comment: You could do a list of list. Or a Dictionary, but it is not observable.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a view model with a list of items that each have another list of items for the ComboBox:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ComboBoxItems { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; } 
        = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
}
```

and visualize it with an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Initialize it like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.ListItems.Add(new ListItem { ComboBoxItems = new string[] { "1.1", "1.2" } });
    vm.ListItems.Add(new ListItem { ComboBoxItems = new string[] { "2.1", "2.2" } });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

It may not even be necessary to have an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel class.

Comment: That breaks the MVVM pattern, which I realize I may have to do.

Comment: No, this doesn't break MVVM. Not sure why you think so.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. All I can say is it needs to stay in the ViewModel class because I can't restructure that much. You're right - it doesn't need to be an observable collection

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a list of list of strings.

When the bound property's Get() is called, there's a function there that retrieves the next list in the list and passes it along.

It's a tad cheesy but it's also a minimal code change.